# How can I plot an interval-valued function in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, intervals

Consider the following definition:

`f[x_]=Piecewise[{{0,x<1/2},{Interval[{0,1}],x==1/2},{1,x>1/2}}];`

Then when one does the `Plot[f[x],{x,0,1}]` of the function, the graph does not depict the interval value `f[1/2]` of the graph.

Any ideas on how to plot interval-valued functions in *Mathematica* would be much appreciated.

Update #1: I've found a hack:

`Plot[ f[x], {x,0,1}, ExclusionsStyle->Opacity[1]];`

The hack, however, does not work on a general interval-valued function, such as

`f[x_]=Piecewise[{{0,x<1/2},{Interval[{0,1}],1/2<=x<=1}}];`

which is the essence of the question.

Update #2:

As a followup to the neat example of @Heike below: it's only a partial solution. For if one tries the following:

`f[x_] = Piecewise[{{0, x < 1/2}, {Interval[{x, 1}], 1/2 <= x <= 1}}];

Plot[ {f[x] /. Interval[a_] :> a[[1]], f[x] /. Interval[a_] :> a[[2]]},

 {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]`

then the graph depicts a segment at x=1/2 that is equal to the value [0,1] instead of [1/2,1].

Comment: Hoe do you think an interval should be depicted, actually?

Comment: As a vertical line segment on the graph: since the element (x,f(x)) of the graph of the function at x=1/2 a closed interval on the real line, I would like Mathematica to be able to graph it for me.

Comment: @Dimitris: `Plot` is not capable of plotting multimaps, only injective functions. Also, I think you'd like to write `Interval[{0,1}]`. As it stands now, this evaluates to `Interval[{0,0}, {1,1}]` which means the union interval of `{0,0}` and `{1,1}`.

Comment: thanks @bbtrv ; I meant the interval, as I write it below - fixed it.

Comment: Since Mma has built-in interval arithmetic, it's a pity that `Plot` is not overloaded to actually plot intervals.

Comment: You could also try `Exclusions -> None` - but that still doesn't give you what you want in your second example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like

```
f[x_]=Piecewise[{{0,x<1/2},{Interval[{0,1}],1/2<=x<=1}}];

Plot[{f[x] /. Interval[a_] :> a[[1]], 
 f[x] /. Interval[a_] :> a[[2]]}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

[image: plotting an interval]